# su & sudo on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, password, sudo

I am trying to use su and sudo on my iMac that I did a fresh clean install of Mac OS X 10.9 and Server 3.0. I explicitly set the password for root with

```
passwd root
```

but when I try to use su or sudo from a local network account, it does not accept the password. When I was reading through some of the man pages for su, sudo and passwd, one of them (but I do not remember which) mentioned something about different behavior in an Open Directory environment. I tried digging around but could not find any more info.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: You don't need to enable the root account to use `sudo`. Are you sure using just an admin account is not enough?

Comment: No, I am trying to stay away from using the local admin account as  much as possible. As such, my desire is to be able to use sudo while logged into a local network account.

Answer (score 2):

```
dsenableroot -u $ADMIN_USERNAME -p $ADMIN_PASSWORD -r $ROOTSNEWPASSWORD
```

replace the variables with your admin username and password as well as the password you desire for root.  At that point, you could sudo as the admin user or just `su -` and use the root password you set to become root.

In the end, you'll want to either configure sudo to allow the commands you use often from your non-admin account or get used to typing the root password when needed.

Comment: I was able to get it to set the password while using the local admin account, as I get the message ***Successfully enabled root user. However, when I try to use su or sudo after setting the password, it will not accept my password.

Comment: @SillyGoof I've added an edit - once you've set root's password, you can su to root, but sudo still won't work with the steps listed above.